# Shift order of elements when '.active' element is ':even' (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to write JQuery code, that will shift order of elements, if 'even' element of certain type is '.active'?  I want to move next (odd) element before active one.
I should probably use .index() and .detach() methods…

Example syntax
http://jsfiddle.net/Tymek/M6qFM/

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="element">1. Pierwszy</div>
    <div class="element">2. Drugi</div>
    <div class="element">3. Trzeci</div>
    <div class="element active">4. Czwarty</div> <!-- 4 is even -->
    <div class="element">5. Piąty</div> <!-- then move this up -->
    <div class="element">6. Szósty</div>
    <div class="element">7. Siódmy</div>
</div>
```

Comment: we expect to see what people tried before asking a question. So: What did you tried?

Comment: if($('#wrap').find('.element:even').hasClass('active')) - but it's obviously naive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can selectively check if the odd-indexed items have the active class, and then move the following item to be before the odd-indexed item.

```
// For each of the odd index elements
$('.element').filter(':odd').each(function(index, element) {
    // If the element has the active class
    if ($(element).hasClass('active')) {
        // Get the next element and move it before the active element
        $(element).next().insertBefore($(element));
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XSDVF/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

No need to check the index when you have `:odd` and `:even` (indices are zero-indexes, so you want to check `:odd` in this case).

```
var $active = $(".active");
if ($active.is(":odd")) {
    $active.next().after($active);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M6qFM/1/